# ExoPlayer PlayerView inflation taking time and causing significant frame drops

Tags: android, android-layout, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

Inflation of com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerView takes close to 25 to 30 ms on an average.
And we are using in viewpager, so everytime user swipes the page, because of PlayerView inflation taking time, there is significant frame drops observed.

Is there any way this can optimised with some attributes / configuration (or) in any other way?

Edit : I am using texture_view as surface type, app:surface_type="texture_view"

- Have raised issue in the github for the same. https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/10066